# Conditional .htaccess rules for same URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the best method to combine the following two rules into one, so that users can visit domain.com/schedule and also domain.com/schedule/{day}

The rule should forward to the same controller, where I will then check the parameter

```
RewriteRule ^schedule/?$ index.php?_orn_shows_action=view-schedule [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^schedule/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?_orn_shows_action=view-schedule&day=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care whether or not you get the `day` parameter without a value, you can just do this:

```
RewriteRule ^schedule(/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?)?)?$ index.php?_orn_shows_action=view-schedule&day=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This would capture these variations:

```
/schedule
/schedule/
/schedule/day
/schedule/day/
```

If you want to make sure not to get an empty `day` parameter, do this:

```
RewriteCond $3      ="" [OR]
RewriteCond &day=$3 ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^schedule(/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?)?)?$ index.php?_orn_shows_action=view-schedule&day=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Finally, if you don't expect to get a query string from the browser on these URLs, I would drop the `QSA` tag, since someone going to `/schedule/monday?day=1` would end up setting `day` equal to 1, instead of to "monday". There's ways to prevent that, but if you don't need the query string, it's easier just to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have to combine it to one - try to switch their positions, second as first and first after that, so your first rule will not catch request that should be analysed by second rule.